# (NOOB) Michael Hartl tutorial how to bring back $ to execute more codes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#code-default_gemfile

I'm on a mac and got everything installed.  My question is...

After putting in the code "rails server"......

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 01:22:34 -0700 Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (0.1ms)

....that shows up in my terminal and i'm not able to execute anymore codes. Like the $ wont show up... I realize this is a total newb question, so please go easy on me haha. (How do i make Austin$ come back so I can continue to code while my app is on the localhost?)  My terminal lets me type, but it just wont execute anything unless I restart it, but that would cause me to do everything over again.  Everytime I press enter it starts a new line without anything pre written such as the usual "Austin$".  It just creates a blank line that with whatever I type, doesn't do anything.

I am VERY new to the terminal and would greatly appreciate feedback!  Thank you SO much for answering. I'm very excited to start coding as this is my first attempt and i'm just glad i did all the installation parts correct hahaha.

Austin

Comment: hit `control+c` it will exit your server or open up a new tab in terminal by `command+t`

Comment: Or start the server in the background. Or start it in the foreground and then move it in the background. "How do I run a program" is really not a programming question, it's a very basic user question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I agree that it is a basic user question. I don't think backgrounding specifically `rails server` is a good idea, because all the output would make further work in the same terminal rather confusing (especially to a beginner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails server` will start the Rails server, and it will continue to execute in your terminal. If you wish to execute further commands, you either have to stop it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), or you need to open another terminal to do it in (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for a new window, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for a new tab)

Comment: Oh I see!  Thank you for such a hasty response!  So is it normal practice to keep the server running and make changes to it in the terminal on a different tab?  Or would it be best to stop the rails server command and change it then restart it?

Comment: While you're in development mode, Rails should reload your code every time it detects a change (i.e. any time you save any file under its control); so yes, normally you would just develop while the server is running.